# maven configuring for alpha, beta, prod builds

Tags: maven

my project will have different resources for alpha, beta, and prod builds.  i use a python script to build and deploy and want to simply pass a variable to the build to say what version we are building.

like this

```
mvn package -DbuildMode=beta
```

i would like to have my resources set up like this

```
java/main/resources
java/main/resources-alpha
java/main/resources-beta
java/main/resources-prod
```

so if i send the beta variable, maven will use

```
java/main/resources
java/main/resources-beta
```

when its building the war file.

how would i begin configuring this in my pom file?  im running maven 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You should use maven profiles.

They can be activated either directly from the command line, or by checking for some environment artifact ( property, file, etc. ).

Here is the article -> http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

In this example it uses property activation

```
<profile>
  <id>beta</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>buildMode</name>
      <value>beta</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        ...
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-beta</directory>
        ...
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</profile>
```